# Comment bundle in TextMate 2 produces errors

Tags: macos, textmate-2

I'm very fond of TextMate's "Comment Line/Selection" bundle, which lets me use ⌘-/ to comment or un-comment highlighted lines. Recently, however, when I use that key combination, I get this error:

> Comment Line / Selection:16:in `require': no such file to load -- /lib/escape (LoadError)

The bundle is in Ruby, and the line of code in question is a require:

```
require "#{ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"]}/lib/escape"
```

I don't see `TM_SUPPORT_PATH` defined in my preferences, and I can't find a file named `escape` on my Mac.

This is TextMate 2.0-alpha.9419. It's possible that a recent update broke this bundle, but I can't quite pin it down. Ideas for how to restore this function would be very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `env ruby` is Ruby 2.0 or 1.9, try either:

- Editing PATH or TM_RUBY in Preferences > Variables.
- Changing `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` to `#!/usr/bin/ruby` Source > Menu Actions > Comments > Comment Line / Selection.

Or try temporarily deleting bundles. From [[TxMt] TM2 error running Comment Line/Selection - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/textmate/K6mVfQb_l8A/_NbuzJAopJAJ):

> Your bundles are likely messed up.
>
> The TM_SUPPORT_PATH comes from the Bundle Support bundle, so you may have uninstalled that.
>
> You can check Preferences → Bundles or remove ~/Library/Application Support/{TextMate,Avian}/ and relaunch to get back to defaults.

TM_SUPPORT_PATH is something like `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared`. Try running `echo $TM_SUPPORT_PATH` or `env` with ⌃R.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling the "Bundle Support" bundle did the trick. (Uninstalling and reinstalling "Source", which provides the actual shortcut, didn't.) I wouldn't have tried that one without this pointer, thanks!